# Are stateless components encouraged for components as of React 16?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, frontend, web-frontend

From the `react` `14.0` [notes](https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/10/07/react-v0.14.html#stateless-functional-components) there was some mention that stateless components will be faster in the future via performance optimizations on the `react` side of things.

Now that we are at version `16.6`, is there any benefit to using them over a `Component` or `PureComponent`?

The headache of having to refactor back to classes if any lifecycle methods/states are needed to be added also needs to be considered in this situation.

Comment: have you heard of hooks yet? you don't ever have to use a class anymore. it's still in alpha but you can pretty much guarantee that if you do everything using functional components now and slowly start using hooks instead of classes you won't be needing classes soon https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

Comment: That's a good article that looks into an effective way to implement a performance optimization, albeit one that would cause even more refactoring - https://medium.com/missive-app/45-faster-react-functional-components-now-3509a668e69f

Comment: @VelimirTchatchevsky I saw that but there were no official sources referenced.

Comment: @azium very interesting, a bit too risky to implement in our current codebase without a clear direction right now though.

Comment: @AdamThompson Performance isn't a big concern in class vs functional components. Both are fast. Classes are faster in native ES6 than in ES5. PureComponent doesn't necessarily provide better performance, always do benchmarks. The risk with hooks seems to be acceptable. Implementation details may change in release but hook API seems to be well-thought already. The problem is that class components look cleaner and more intelligible, there's too much magic in hooks that may be tricky to read, maintain, test and possibly debug. For now I'd go with classes and augment them with hooks where needed.

Comment: @estus thanks, and great point about PureComponents - if the Component has to render every time anyways then just adding a shallow equal on the props will just slow things down.